# Why does this naive Python paired Fastq reader work?

Tags: python, fastq

I wrote some throwaway code for ingesting paired-end reads from a Fastq file into memory.

```py
def ingest(stream1, stream2):
    while True:
        record1, record2 = list(), list()
        for _ in range(4):
            record1.append(next(stream1))
            record2.append(next(stream2))
        yield record1, record2
```

I had initially put the `for` loop in a `try/Except` block, anticipating I'd need to explicitly break out of the endless `while` loop. However, the code seems to work correctly even after I removed it. I even "corrupted" the final read in one of the paired files, and the `ingest` function performs reasonably (the last read pair is never `yield`ed).

My question is...**why does this code work**, since I never explicitly break out of the loop?

Here's an example of how the code is invoked.

```py
>>> with open('seqR1.fastq', 'r') as fh1, open('seqR2.fastq', 'r') as fh2:
...     counter = 0
...     for r1, r2 in interleave(fh1, fh2):
...         counter += 1
>>> counter
5000
>>> r1
['@read5000/1\n', 'AGGTCTGGGGACAGGTGTTTTACAGGCTCCTTTAGGGGTGGCAAGTCTCCCGGAAACATGATTAGTGAAGACACGTTAACAGCGAAACTGACAGAGAACCTCAACATTCTCTGGTAGGAAAAGCCAGGATCCTGGCAGAGGAAGCAACGATTCGAGCAGGGAACTGTGCAGGACAGAGAACAATGCGGCCCCAATTTTGATCCAGGGGTAGTTAGCTTAGCTAAGGAGTTCCCCAGTCCCTAAGTGGAGAGGGGATCCAGAACCCTACAATTTATTATTATATCTTAGCGGATATATCTAT\n', '+\n', 'CCCCCGGGEGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG@GGGGGGGFAGGGCGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGCGGGGGDGGGGFGGGGGGGGGCGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGCGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG@G<GGGGGGGGGGGGFGGFGFF:DGGFFCGGGGCGGFEGGGGGGEGGGFB:GGGDG=FGGGG,GAGGGDGGFGGGCD3GFG+G?G*FGGG<GCGGGGC@CD<FFGF*:+G=FE<;GG,8C7GF=;9D=G<C5C66G6C>7)FD*6G7D)9;*C:)4D5+9>@G*=0):)*;1*504\n']
>>> r2
['@read5000/2\n', 'TGTGGGGTTCTGGATCCCCTCTCCACTTAGGGACTGGGGAACTCCTTAGCTAAGCTAATTACCCCTGGATCAAAATTGGGGCCGCATTGTTCTCTGTCCTGCACAGTTCCCTGCTCGAATCGTTGCTTCCTCTGCCAGGATCCTGGCTTTTCCTACCAGAGAATGTTGAGGTTCTCTGTCATTTTCGCTGCTAATGTGTCTTCACTAATCGTGTTTCCGGGAGACTTGCCACCCCTAAAGGAGCTTGTTGAACACTTGTCACCAGACCTAAGTCCTTAGGGATGAACCTGTGTCTCGGCAC\n', '+\n', 'CCCCBGC9FGCD-GGGFGGGEFEFF@CCGFGGGGFF+DG6,F69+FGG+FGF<FCC;GGEBFGGEDECFGGG6GDG7BFG9GCG9G9GDGGGG<GDFFFGEGC,<GC=GFG:,:A:EE+GD<:E,FGF=FCAGEFF++G,G,<EGGFGFFA>*FG9EGFCFCGC,B>43GFF@E@2>9ED@,568D=A;C+=5@E/F53D>,6F*9@+,E,C=*0+*@56<*9@:/F,1,:*)*14*0CC=*1)*0*,*)0;+)*))/**)**;0;//9)1+)10.()5/)070*)7*C**3/)(2*****\n']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code only runs prior to Python 3.7, now it raises `RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration`. This is essentially a bug fix described in [PEP 479 -- Change StopIteration handling inside generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/). You can enable the new behaviour from Python 3.5 via `from __future__ import generator_stop`.

Note, it's not related to file-handles per se, you can reproduce it with a smaller example with a simple iterator:

```
it = iter([1,2])

def f(it):
    while True:
        yield next(it)

print(list(f(it)))
```

You should not write code relying on the bug

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: **[Chris_Rands's answer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/11311/4980) is more authoritative and clarifies that this behavior is essentially a bug.**  (I had only tested my example on Python 3.6.8 and hadn't seen PEP 479.)

When `next` runs out of lines, it raises `StopIteration`, and apparently that stops the while loop similarly to calling `break` without you needing to catch the exception.  I couldn't see a definitive source on that but you can see it in action if you catch and re-raise the exception:

```
def ingest2(stream1, stream2):
    while True:
        try:
            record1, record2 = list(), list()
            for _ in range(4):
                record1.append(next(stream1))
                record2.append(next(stream2))
            yield record1, record2
        except StopIteration:
            print("StopIteration raised")
            raise
```

You can also try to catch it outside the loop, but it doesn't get re-raised at that point.  (If you try raising one yourself in a while loop, though, it *doesn't* catch it in the same way, so there must be some extra Python magic going on.  I can't see any difference between the two exception objects so I'd be curious what's going on there.)  Neat example.  You could also make a pair of FASTQ parsers using Biopython's [SeqIO.parse](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO#sequence-input) for more complex/permanent situations if needed.